# Testing android apps with TDD vs Debugger

Tags: android, tdd, android-debug

I would like to ask something interesting. When I am developing native android apps,and want to make sure that there no null objects,I use the debugger as shown.

[image: debugger]

So I put a break point in the line I want,I step over my code and the fun begins:). However,there is this TDD,which I have never used. Are they any specific tools for that? Is it more efficient?

Regards,

Theo.

Comment: @Joni this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDD is generally a better approach as it stands for Test Driven Development and its idea is to have reproducable tests to validate your code against. A good way to do so is to read youself into JUnit which is also included in Android Studio.

EDIT: Also TDD is generally more Efficient as you notice errors much earlier and you write better code